# Mypy and Inheriting from a class that is an attribute on an instance

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, mypy, typechecking, python-typing

## EDIT

The issue arises when trying to inherit from a class that is an attribute of an instance. This mcve repros it, I'll leave the rest of the question below for posterity:

```py
class A:
    class SubA:
        pass


a = A()

class B(a.SubA):
    pass
```

`mypy` output:

```
Name 'a.SubA' is not defined
```

This passes:

```py
class A:
    class SubA:
        pass


class B(A.SubA):
    pass
```

The example in this [Related Issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8603) is pretty much exactly what `Flask-SQLAlchemy` does to provide the declarative base class under the `db` namespace. In the issue, `mypy` maintainer asserts that they wouldn't support the pattern.

My question is, what is incorrect about the above pattern such that `mypy` would not support it? Especially in the context that it is used by a large project such as `Flask-SQLAlchemy`.

Further, what is the best way for users of `Flask-SQLAlchemy` and `mypy` to manage this in their projects?

---

## ORIGINAL QUESTION

This question isn't about the lack of `Flask-SQLAlchemy` stubs. Accepting that, I came across this question.

Please help me to understand why the following does not work as I expect.

In my environment I have only `Flask-SQLAlchemy` and `mypy` installed.

I have `mypy` configured with `ignore_missing_imports = True`.

A `mypy` pass over the following:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()


class Widget(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

reveals:

```
error: Name 'db.Model' is not defined
```

So, I've attempted to subclass `SQLAlchemy` to provide an annotation for `Model`, which shows in `__annotations__` on the object, yet the `mypy` analysis of the module doesn't change:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_sqlalchemy.model import DefaultMeta


class TypedSQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    Model: DefaultMeta


db = TypedSQLAlchemy()

print(db.__annotations__)  # {'Model': <class 'flask_sqlalchemy.model.DefaultMeta'>}


class Widget(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

When I execute the file, the `print(db.__annotations__)` command displays `{'Model': <class 'flask_sqlalchemy.model.DefaultMeta'>}`, yet still `mypy` has the same error:

```
error: Name 'db.Model' is not defined
```

I would expect that providing an annotation for `db.Model` should make that error go away.

### Earlier Edit

I've initially misinterpreted the error as it doesn't suggest the attribute `Model` doesn't exist on `db`, it suggests that the name `db.Model` doesn't exist in the namespace. But why would it treat `db.Model` as a full name, and not `db` as the name defined locally and `Model` as it's attribute? Is this something to do with trying to inheriting from a class variable?

Also, my annotation was incorrect, should be:

```py
class TypedSQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    Model: Type[DefaultMeta]
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use `A.SubA`.

As I know access to nested class via instance variable is not allowed from `mypy` point of view. Because derived classes from `A` could override nested class, and mypy cannot recognize this case, something like this:

```
class A:
    class SubA:
        pass

class C(A):
    class SubA:
        pass
    
def foo(a: A):
    class B(a.SubA):  # What SubA here ?
        pass

foo(C())
```

Update:

As for Flask-SQLAlchemy, the following workaround was suggested in [this](https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs/issues/76) discussion:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeMeta

BaseModel: DeclarativeMeta = db.Model


class MyModel(BaseModel): ...
```

> If you are using flask_sqlalchemy then you can use from `flask_sqlalchemy.model import DefaultMeta` instead of `DeclarativeMeta`.

Comment: Of course, but my hands are tied by `Flask-SQLAlchemy`. It constructs an instance of which the `Model` base class is an attribute and that is assigned to the instance inside `__init__`. There are workarounds like assigning the class to a module scoped variable but I'd rather stick to the convention of accessing everything to the `db` variable if possible (and preferably without `# type: ignore`'s everywhere!)

Comment: I do appreciate your example though! Very helpful.

Comment: For Flask-SQLAlchemy is similar. You can not use db.Model